# Is there a file copy utility for OS X that's similar to TeraCopy for Windows?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, utilities, switching, copy-paste

On Windows, I use [TeraCopy](http://www.codesector.com/teracopy.php) for improved file copying. Are there any similar equivalents for OS X?

In particular, I'd like to see things like copy speed.

Comment: If you can treat the Mac drive as an external drive, like a NAS, and do the copy from a windows machine, file pilot copy would work for you. They have a free “no registration required” eval download at http://www.filepilotsoftware.com . It is super fast, particularly for update copies, and has an easy to use GUI interface (but can also be run in a batch mode like a script).

Comment: Doesn't osx's own copier do just that?

Comment: @foley do just what? afaik, it just shows you a progress bar. teracopy has considerably more features.

Comment: If you would list the specific features past a progress bar and time estimate, people here might have more suggestions. Are you still looking for a solution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I looked around for something like [TeraCopy](http://www.codesector.com/teracopy) a while back but everything I found was pretty horrid.  In the end I decided to just use `cp` and `rsync` on the command line.

Comment: aha, that makes sense.

Answer (score 7):

The best suggestions from this thread are:

- [Pathfinder](http://www.cocoatech.com/)
- [XFile](http://rixstep.com/4/0/xfile/)
- [UltraCopier](http://ultracopier.first-world.info/)
- [MiniCopier](http://www.adriancourreges.com/projects/minicopier/)

Comment: Consider ForkLift: http://www.binarynights.com/forklift/.

Answer (score 4):

Since you mentioned “better” and in particular “copy speed”, I believe the only answer is [Xfile](http://rixstep.com/4/0/xfile/). Other than that, nothing will beat cp ;)

> The world’s fastest file manager for OS X

It’s not free, quite the contrary.

Comment: XFile also crashes **a lot**, and is not particularly fast *at all*, at least in my experience.

Answer (score 4):

Try [Ultracopier](http://ultracopier.first-world.info/), looks a bit like TeraCopy and works on Mac & PC

Comment: What is meant with the "All copy" and "from into" and "Copyhandler"?

Answer (score 3):

While much more than just a copy utility, [Pathfinder](http://www.cocoatech.com/) shows copy speed. Along with Launchbar, it's one of my must have utilities.

Comment: This is the most useful answer of all

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is nearly 12 years old and may be obsolete but there is actually official [TeraCopy for Mac](https://www.codesector.com/teracopy-for-mac).

Answer (score 2):

An app I developed, Ultracopier, fits your use case.

Here is a [YouTube demo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=a1OAgWgwSTE) showcasing the PC version in action.

Answer (score 1):

Have you first compared speeds between TeraCopy and the built in Mac OS X file copy? I hate to sound like a generic condescending Mac user, but what exactly is wrong with the built in one?

Comment: I would like to compare speeds, but the built in one does not tell me the copy speed. Unless there is a way?

Comment: With maths...? Find a folder of weighty size (or a large file, but you'll get different results for one vs many files) and find out its size. Time how long it takes to copy. Divide size by time it took to copy, and you'll get the average speed.

Comment: It would be nice if the UI would simply display the copy rate, as opposed to me having to do division. Because I'm lazy. :)

Comment: Or you can install iStat (http://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/) and see the disk throughput in a nice graph/number…

Answer (score 1):

You may also consider [Hedge for Mac](http://hedgeformac.com) tool. It's mostly for backup purposes and can be used to fast copy large files/folders. It has free version but most interesting features are to be paid.

Answer (score 0):

There is one application that I found online that works similar to TeraCopy, and that, too, is for Mac OS X and named [Turbo Copy Pro](http://www.turbocopypro.com/).

This is a multi-function application and you can view the copy speed and also pause and resume the copy process similar to TeraCopy. The only drawback it has is that it is not free.

I have tried and tested the trial version and it worked absolutely fine. Please have a look and post your review.