# TeraCopy like for Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, file-transfer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a file copy utility for OS X that's similar to TeraCopy for Windows?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4412/is-there-a-file-copy-utility-for-os-x-thats-similar-to-teracopy-for-windows)

Is there any OS X app similar to TeraCopy in Windows?
I like where I can resume copy from external drive after someone accidentally pulls the USB cable and put it back again.